# How to export Estimator's best model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a simple CNN based on a Custom Estimator with TF Records.
I am trying to export the best model in terms of validation loss during the `train_and_evaluate` phase.

According to the documentation of the `tf.estimator.BestExporter`, I should feed a function that returns a `ServingInputReceiver` but after doing so, the `train_and_evaluate` phase crashes with a `NotFoundError: model/m01/eval; No such file or directory`.

Seems like if the BestExporter does not permit saving the evaluation results as it would do without the exporter. I tried with different `ServingInputReceiver` but I keep getting the same error.

As defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators):

```
feature_spec = {
        'shape': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature((43), tf.int64)
    }

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[120, 120, 3],
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'image': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BestExporter#__init__)

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)
        }
    return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
```

Here are my exporter and training procedure:

```
exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
    name="best_exporter",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
    exports_to_keep=5)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(train_path, True, epochs, batch_size))

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(eval_path, perform_shuffle=False, batch_size=1),
    exporters=exporter)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(ben_classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

[This is a gist](https://gist.github.com/hichameyessou/f2710391066f6ed5786693892ac93dbe) with the output.
What's the correct way to define a `ServingInputReceiver` for the `BestExporter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the code shown below:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    """
    This is used to define inputs to serve the model.
    :return: ServingInputReciever
    """
    reciever_tensors = {
        # The size of input image is flexible.
        'image': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 1]),
    }

    # Convert give inputs to adjust to the model.
    features = {
        # Resize given images.
        'image': tf.reshape(reciever_tensors[INPUT_FEATURE], [-1, INPUT_SHAPE])
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(receiver_tensors=reciever_tensors,
                                                    features=features)
```

Then use `tf.estimator.BestExporter` as shown below:

```
best_exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
        exports_to_keep=1)
    exporters = [best_exporter]
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={input_name: eval_data},
        y=eval_labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn=eval_input_fn,
        throttle_secs=10,
        start_delay_secs=10,
        steps=None,
        exporters=exporters)

    # Train and evaluate the model.
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

For more info, refer the link:
https://github.com/yu-iskw/tensorflow-serving-example/blob/master/python/train/mnist_keras_estimator.py

Comment: Hi, would you mind elaborating on what makes the answer work? Many thx!